# How to use vim shortcuts with Notepad++

Tags: editor, notepad++

I have to use Notepad++ and not the Windows version of vim because I am sure that Notepad++ does not insert odd characters to the end of lines. I am editing my dev box, so I have to edit from Windows, but a lot of editors are adding odd characters to my files. I like using vim key shortcuts because they are efficient. Is there a way to use Vim shortcuts with Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are seeing nothing more than the difference in end of line marking between Windows and Unix.

So to fix the issues you are seeing just configure your editor to use the correct end of line marker.